# Sandcastle warnings for autogenerated XAML controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, sandcastle

In my C# WPF project, I have a user control that contains some controls that are just declared in XAML but are used in the code behind (setting visibility based on other properties).
When documenting the project with Sandcastle, I get a "ShowMissingComponent" warning for each of these controls complaining thet they do not have a summary tag. As they are only generated in the .designer.cs file, I cannot provide that summary because the file is regenerated from time to time.

How can I suppress these Sandcastle warnings (as I tend to keep my build log clean of warnings...)?